# Angular 8. How to assign observable value to service property in constructor?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular application I have service for making requests to rest API. Before make any call I need to get unique guid from backend and pass it as parameter to every call. So I thought I can make request inside constructor and assign result to property like this:

```
export class BaseApiService<T> implements OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  protected tenantGuid: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.subscription = this.getGuid().subscribe(data => {
        this.tenantGuid = data;
     });
  }

  private getGuid(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/Tenants`);
  }
}
```

But property `tenentGuid` is still undefined after constructor executed in derived service.

```
export class TasksService extends BaseApiService<TaskModel> {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(httpClient);
  }

  public list(): Observable<TaskModel[]> {

   return this.httpClient.get<TaskModel[]>(this.generateUrl(), {params: {tenantguid: this.tenantGuid}})
  }

}
```

I understand that this associated with asynchronous, but I don't find out how to achieve result in another way.

Would be appreciated for any advise)

Comment: Where did you try to print `tenentGuid`, so that it printed `undefined`?

Comment: I call method in derived service, so i see that call for getting guid is executed, but when another method from this service called this.tenentGuid is undefined.

Comment: Can you please show, how do you call it from the derived class? You got to subscribe over there.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: This issue is pretty similar to 'access token' pattern when the app can't call an API endpoint without access token obtained first. Typically this should be resolved as part of the application initialization cycle. Like you could tie obtaining tenantGuid to login flow's side effect. Question when in your case you call "list()" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something more like this:

NOTE: NOT syntax checked.

**Base class**

```
export class BaseApiService<T> implements OnDestroy {

  protected tenantGuid$ = this.http.get<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/Tenants`).pipe(
     shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

**Class**

```
export class TasksService extends BaseApiService<TaskModel> {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(httpClient);
  }

  public list$ = this.tenantGuid$.pipe(
        switchMap(tenantguid => 
        this.httpClient.get<TaskModel[]>(this.generateUrl(), {params: {tenantguid: this.tenantGuid}})
  ))
 }
```

Using a declarative approach, you can define the stream that provides the GUID. Pipe it through shareReplay so the value is replayed to any other stream that uses it.

Then in the class, when a GUID value is emitted, get the related data. If your UI is then bound to list$ using an async pipe, it will automatically update with the retrieved data when it is returned.

UPDATE:

You could also use a routing resolver to ensure your GUID is retrieved before routing to your first route. But that may cause a delay in the startup of your application.

Comment: I came here to answer it but @DeborahK is here and I learnt while watching her course :) .

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Subject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/) from **rxjs** to deal with asynchronous call. You have to call `list()` once the `guid` is received

```
export class BaseApiService<T> implements OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  protected tenantGuid: string;

  protected guidChange: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>()

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.subscription = this.getGuid().subscribe(data => {
        this.tenantGuid = data;
        this.guidChange.next(); // emit guid received event
     });
  }

  private getGuid(): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.get<string>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/Tenants`);
  }
}
```

derived class

```
export class TasksService extends BaseApiService<TaskModel> {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    super(httpClient);
    this.guidChange.subscribe(()=> {
      this.list(); // by now guid should be set
    })
  }

  public list(): Observable<TaskModel[]> {

   return this.httpClient.get<TaskModel[]>(this.generateUrl(), {params: {tenantguid: this.tenantGuid}})
  }

}
```